# How to automate Unity registration?

Tags: c#, unity-container, repository-pattern, abstract, radix

In my code i have many repeated actions like this.
I want to write 1 generic method (with reflection) to automate this process of registration repositories for this objects with one base class

```
        _container.RegisterType(typeof(IFinanceRepository<User, int>), typeof(UsersRepository), new TransientLifetimeManager(), new InjectionMember[] { });
        _container.RegisterType(typeof(IFinanceRepository<News, int>), typeof(NewsRepository), new TransientLifetimeManager(), new InjectionMember[] { });
        _container.RegisterType(typeof(IFinanceRepository<Currency, int>), typeof(CurrenciesRepository), new TransientLifetimeManager(), new InjectionMember[] { });
        _container.RegisterType(typeof(IFinanceRepository<Language, int>), typeof(LanguagesRepository), new TransientLifetimeManager(), new InjectionMember[] { });
```

And

```
public class UsersRepository : EFFinanceRepository<User, int>
```

All objects (Users, News, e.t.c. have base interface - IObject there T - is type of ID property (Guid, int, etc)

```
 public class User : IObject<int>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// every object ID
    /// </summary>
    public int ID { get; set; }
```

All repositories have base class

```
IOvolimeFinanceRepository<T, in IDType>
```

Where T - IObject (User, News)
IDType - Type of ID property each object i

Help me, please generane full abstract generic method to automate this !

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into using a Unity extension that add convention based registration.  There are a few out there.  I have not used any of them, but I have used conventions based registration with Castle Windsor and I absolutely love it.

- [Unity Auto Registration](http://autoregistration.codeplex.com/)
- [ConventionExtension](https://code.google.com/p/conventionextension/)
- [UnityConfiguration](https://github.com/thedersen/UnityConfiguration)
- [Advanced Configuration Engine for Unity](http://tecx.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=AdvancedConfigurationEngineForUnity&referringTitle=Home)

Answer (score 0):

You need add simple interface for you repository main interface (IOvolimeFinanceRepository) - IGenericRepository

```
var types = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes();

        var concreteRepositoryTypes = (from t in types
                                       where !t.IsAbstract && typeof(IGenericRepository).IsAssignableFrom(t)
                                       select t).ToList();

        foreach (var repositoryType in concreteRepositoryTypes)
        {
            //register like _container.RegisterType(typeof(UsersRepository), typeof(UsersRepository), new TransientLifetimeManager(), new InjectionMember[] { });
            _container.RegisterType(repositoryType, new TransientLifetimeManager(), new InjectionMember[] { });

            var interfaceForRepository = repositoryType.GetInterfaces().FirstOrDefault(x => x != typeof(IGenericRepository));

            if(interfaceForRepository != null)
                _container.RegisterType(interfaceForRepository, repositoryType, new TransientLifetimeManager(), new InjectionMember[] { });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Unity comes with Registration by Convention already.

You didn't mention which version you were targeting. I'm pretty sure this is available since Unity 3.0

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn507479%28v=pandp.30%29.aspx